# Updated FSharp.Data and now getting an error on the build server

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a FSharp project that uses FSharp.Data.  I upgraded the project to point to .NET Framework 4.6.2 and use FSharp.Core 4.7.0.  It works fine locally using VS2019 but when it runs on the build server, I am seeing this:

> error FS3033(0,0): Error : The design-time type 'System.String'
>   utilized by a type provider was not found in the target reference
>   assembly set

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: What version of the Visual Studio build environment is installed on the build server? If it's less than VS2019, you may not be getting FSharp.Core 4.7.0 in which case you're getting a different `System.String` type than the one the type provider is referencing.